# How to increase cap in Tiger Woods 08?

Tags: tiger-woods-pga-tour-08

I've been playing *Tiger Woods PGA Tour 08* for a while now. For a while I thought my skills were going up (progressing from amateur to legend), but I noticed that when I got to around **Pro** level that my stats hadn't seemed to have any effect on my gameplay.

So I had a look at the stats screen and noticed that I have a yellow line capping me at 10% and what was increasing was my potential. How do I remove the cap or make it increase? I've won a few tournies on the tour so I thought it might go up after winning my first one, then maybe my second one, now I'm on about 7 so I'm guessing that's not it.

Any ideas? Its really ruining the gameplay for me. Although the difficulty at having a golfer so technically challenged is actually quite fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to beat the "boss" golfers (the ones in the center of each of the Tiger Challenge clusters) to increase that yellow skill cap.

I believe that's the only way to make the skill increases you earn actually apply.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are not adjusting the attributes for your career character.  Yes, this is a year later but I just saw this looking for something else.  Each time you play in a tournament you gain experience points.  Then you should go into attributes and spend those points to increase your abilities.  With the EA Sports $30,000.00 driver, my character can drive a tee shot to 409 yards using "Power Shot" or 376 in "Full" swing mode.  Attributes are located using this click sequence:

Game Face:
Attributes:
    Spend points as desired.

But seriously, I hope you have learned this a long time before now.  That or you are the world's most patient person.  :-)

Comment: I don't think you read the question properly. I can spend attributes, but each are maxed until I beat the "boss golfers" in the other answer